# Hide Text when check box option is ticked in customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

[image: my localhost screenshot]

How I hide the Head Text which is "Magna Aliquam" when "Hide Head Text" checkbox is checked and show when the checkbox is unchecked.

Below is my code, but I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated

```
wp.customize( 'hide_head_text', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        if($("hide_head_text").is(':checked'))
            $(".welcome-text h2").hide();  // checked
        else
            $(".welcome-text h2").show();  // unchecked
    } )( jQuery );
```

Comment: WordPress customizer by default has this feature enabled.I am currently looking in my WordPress "js" folder for working example. If anybody can point to it that would be great.

Comment: If you don't use postMessage then this will be a lot simpler... Just add something like this in your theme's functions.php file:  
`add_action( 'wp_head', function() { echo ( get_theme_mod( 'hide_head_text', 0 ) ) ? '<style>.welcome-text h2 { display: none; }</style>' : ''; } );`